# copying bash completion (without copying the actual code)

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Suppose I have a command `git-local` (it could be a Bash function or a binary in `/usr/local/bin`) and suppose I would like `git-local` to have the same tab completion as the command `git` has. Finally, suppose that I'm efficient (read lazy) and I don't want to go find the code that the `git` commmand uses to manually copy over and bloat my .bashrc (or whatever external file I paste it in and the source). Is there a simple way I can have `git-local` use the same autocompletion as `git`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[8.7 Programmable Completion Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html):

> If the `-p` option is supplied, or if no options are supplied, existing completion specifications are printed in a way that allows them to be reused as input.

Something like

```
$(complete -p git | awk '$NF="git-local"')
```

maybe?

E.g.:

```
$ complete -p foobar
-bash: complete: foobar: no completion specification
$ complete -p traceroute
complete -F _known_hosts traceroute
$ $(complete -p traceroute | awk '$NF="foobar"')
$ complete -p foobar
complete -F _known_hosts foobar
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason from `$ complete -p git` I get `bash: complete: git: no completion specification`. Must be something wrong with my setup.